# Access Query Showing Information from a city from a different state

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query that will pull tax rates into transactions for the entire U.S. The issue I have run into is there are multiple states that have the same counties and cites and are pulling different rates. Example Decatur TX will pull in the Decatur AL rate. What can I do to stop this?

```
SELECT 
Query1.STORE_NUM, Query1.ST_CD, 
Query1.[Juris Cd], Query1.CITY_NM, Query1.[Document Date], 
Query1.[Amount in local currency], Query1.[Rental Tax], 
Query1.[State Rate], Query1.[County Rate],
IIf(IsNull([City_Rates].[City_Rate]),0,[City_Rates].[City_Rate]) AS [City Rate]

FROM 
Query1 LEFT JOIN City_Rates ON Query1.CITY_NM = City_Rates.City

WHERE 
(((Query1.ST_CD)="GA"));
```

Comment: try using a JOIN on both the city and state fields

Comment: What's the schema of your `City` table? Unless your city table has a column that can map back to a particular State, this query wont work...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you have a state code in each table, so you should `join` on that as well:

```
FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN
     City_Rates
     ON Query1.CITY_NM = City_Rates.City AND
        Query1.ST_CD = City_Rates.ST_CD
```

I think access will allow multiple conditions in the `on` for a `left join` when both refer to the tables.  If not, a close approximation is:

```
FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN
     City_Rates
     ON Query1.CITY_NM = City_Rates.City
WHERE (Query1.ST_CD = City_Rates.ST_CD or City_Rates.City IS NULL)
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1.  I'm pretty sure MS-Access supports multi-column joins.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining to `City` based on just name.  But name is not enough to uniquely identify a city.

If the `City` and transactions table both contain a state, you could join on two columns:

```
LEFT JOIN City_Rates 
  ON Query1.CITY_NM = City_Rates.City
     AND Query1.ST_CD = City_Rates.StateCode
```